# Prevent multine of inline elements to start by a separator

Tags: css

Ok so here something that I can't find an easy way to deal with. I have a list of links, it can be tags for exemple or anything, and I want to display all of them separated by a separator. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/wq6ck4d0/).

The problem is that because elements are of an unknown length and need to break on mulline (a tag can have a long name for example), sometimes the separator is the first element of the line, it's uggly. Do you have any way to prevent this wrapping before the separator `span`?

```css
.list {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  max-width: 290px;
}
.list > * {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.list > span {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor ipsum amet dolor long foo bar baz lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
<span>/</span>
</div>
```

Comment: (Post some existing HTML/CSS.)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: HTML and CSS added in the post

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helps you,

```css
.list {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.list > * {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.list > .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.list > .wrapper > span {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
    <span>/</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `::after`, for example:

```html
<div class="list">
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></span>
</div>
```

```css
.list {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.list > * {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.list > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.list > span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '/';
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lby5u1st/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to handle this. I'll give a few examples. The crux of the issue is that you're depending on HTML to style your webpage. HTML will handle the flow of content, but really it should just be providing semantic meaning to the page and not providing any stylistic decoration.

## The `content` + pseudo element method

We can remove the separators from the HTML and add them via CSS instead using [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content). This will also allow us to not show a separator for the last item.

Then we can set our list items to be `inline-block` which will still allow them to flow together, and add `no-wrap` for our whitespace which will prevent the separator from appearing as the first item on the list.

```css
.list {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.list > * {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.list > *:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '/';
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Lorem dolor</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a>
</div>
```

## *Just* the pseudo element method

There's still an issue with the above code. Though we've removed the separators from the HTML we're still using **content** as styling. If a screen reader was to encounter the above markup it would read something like this: "Lorem *forward slash* Lorem ipsum *forward slash* Dolor *forward slash*, etc". HTML is meant to provide semantic meaning, and then we use CSS to provide styling so we can push this further by styling our pseudo element as the separator and removing it from the `content` attribute.

```css
.list {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.list > * {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.list > *:not(:last-child)::after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: '';
  height: .8em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px -2px;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor amet</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with that is that iwth `inline-block` I lose the ability of the text wrapping. With long sentences it wrap the whole line to a new line, but I need to keep inline text and wrap only last word with spacer, not the whole line, Here is the updated example : https://jsfiddle.net/a38ndpyg/

Comment: I'll have to consider this a bit more. I've never encountered a problem like what you're describing which is basically "If an ornament is on its own line, hide the ornament" and it would likely require JavaScript. There isn't a method with only CSS that I'm aware of that will solve this.